# Is it ideal to run a WP Cron job every 24 hours to update all the posts' taxonomy field?

Tags: wordpress, cron

The title says it all. I have a custom taxonomy field in Wordpress that I plan to be updated automatically by running a Wordpress CRON job every 24 hours. I am wondering if this is an efficient way to go because I have a lot of posts on my site which is so far around 5000 + posts. If there is a better way to go with this, I would like to know as well.

Comment: Why not - that's what cron is for. You may want to chunk up the posts so it only runs 100 or so every 10 minutes. This will decrease the load on the server.

Answer (score 0):

CRON is a good way to do this, but it could suffer from timeouts as your website scales. MySQL Event Scheduler is a good alternative when manipulating just the database.